# My Huawei mobile broadband not detected

Tags: 12.04

I have a huawei EC178 usb but it is not detected in ubuntu. it works well in windows but could not install it inubuntu.please guide.

Comment: Dear, my USB modem still not detected by machine. Please explain as I am very new in ubuntu.

Comment: My $ lsusb and usb-devices have following output.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use Modem Manager.

You can install it here:

[image]